# Error: SIGSEGV when opening a second form in Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, segmentation-fault

I just wrote my first program with two forms and got the error "external: sigsegv" when clicking on the MenuItem2 in the program with following code

```
procedure TForm1.MenuItem2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;
```

During compiling I don't get an error and I've added my unit2 to the uses of unit1 which contains the mentioned procedure. I've read something about autocreating the form which might solve my problem but still have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Where is your code to create Form2?

Comment: When do I have to create it and how do I do it? I just have it in my unit 2 with all the child objects.

Comment: Create before you need it. It all depends when that is. Impossible to say from here.